# Finding both count and average of a column in R data.table, after group by

Tags: data-mining, r

I have a data table of 5 columns. I want to do a group by on one column  and want to get the count of another column, `id`.

I do this in this way:  `dt[,length(id),by=dt$cid]`.

If I also want to get `sum of id`, how do I proceed?
I tried this:

```
dt[,(sum(id) length(id)),by=dt$cid]
```

but it did not work. Could you please help out.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the sqldf package.

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). Your syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get but the `sum` and `length` of `id` with `data.table`, you can do it like this:

```
dt[,.(total=sum(id), n=length(id)), by=cid]
```

You could even write this in shorter format with the `.N` operator of `data.table`:

```
dt[,.(total=sum(id), .N), by=cid]
```

Comment: +1 for using `.N`.  This is probably the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use tapply,

```
with(dt,tapply(id, cid, FUN=sum))
```

Comment: This will only find the `sum`. And it is better to say "You *could* use"

Answer (score 1):

You can use tapply or aggregate along with a custom function.

> aggregate(Id~cid, data=dt, FUN=function(x) c(mn=mean(x),ln=length(x)))

You may like to see my blog where I discuss few other scenario.

http://r4sqlminded.blogspot.com/2015/06/selecting-data-from-data-frame.html